# How do you produce iron?

Tags: kittens-game

So this is the first time I've played the Kittens Game and I have no idea what I have to do to get iron? I need it for some upgrades but so far I don't get how to produce it.
Help??

Comment: Have you researched "Metal Working" in the science tab?

Answer (score 11):

Iron is produced by Smelters from Minerals and Wood. Smelters can be built once you've discovered Metal Working. You also need to research Construction to unlock Iron.

Comment: And to head off the next (highly common) question, once you've built smelters, *make sure to turn them on* or they won't produce anything.  (The +/- buttons on the Smelter control that.)

Comment: That means click the text `Smelter (0|0)`, to build a smelter. Which makes it `Smelter (1|0)`. Then click the `+` button to make it `Smelter (1|1)` to being production.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you could unlock Iron before Construction and use it on things like upgrading your farming/woodcutting equipment.

Answer (score 1):

**To make your first iron:**

1) Research [Science] 'Mining' to unlock the 'mine' building.

2) Research [Science] 'Metal Working' to unlock the 'smelter' building.

3) Assign at least one kitten as a miner to produce minerals.

4) Assign at least one kitten as a woodcutter to produce wood (fuel).

5) Build a smelter and turn it on.

6) A smelter consumes minerals and wood and produces iron.